# Increasing brightness of ExoPlayer 2 just like MxPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I went through the entire documentation of `ExoPlayer2`, but couldn't find how to increase the brightness of `exoplayer`. I found a similar question

[on github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2450)

My xml is as follows

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exoplayer_view_activity_exo_player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:resize_mode="fill"
        app:show_timeout="0"
        app:use_controller="true" />
```

If I use SurfaceView instead how I am going to use the methods of `exoplayer`. I tried placing my exoplayer tag in surface view tag but my app crashed. Is there any other way to increase brightness of `exoplayer`. Please don't paste code to increase system brightness.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the `ExoPlayer2` library's internal `SurfaceView` at [`ExoPlayer/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2) or the utils classes that control pixels and their "lightness" depending on how you want your brightness achieved.

You could also simply use the `ExVidPlayer` media playback library [here](https://github.com/karanvs/ExVidPlayer). The library builds upon `ExoPlayer2` and provides built in brightness control.